# Why Android studio is refusing to share project on GitHub?

Tags: windows, android-studio, kotlin, github, version-control

I have an android project in Android Studio which I would like to share on GitHub. Earlier I have shared other projects. But after resetting my PC and installing relevant softwares Android Studio doesn't take my github credentials, so I can't post the project. These are the images respectively.

[image: Step 1]

[image: Step 2]

[image: Step 3]

[image: Step 4]

Answer (score 1):

For those who are wondering, I have found the solution. Please follow these steps to solve the issue.
Go to File->Settings (Ctrl+Alt+S).
Then, Version Control->GitHub.
Choose the account. In my case it was showing "Bad credentials" with **login** option. After providing **GitHub** password, click OK. Then I followed the original steps as shown in the question. It solved the problem.

[image: sol1]

[image: sol2]

Comment: Don't forget to restart Android Studio after. Still had the error even after replacing credentials.